# Filtering contentEditable on client and server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, contenteditable, dry

**I'm developing a Rails web app using the contentEditable feature of HTML 5**, in the style of Google Docs and others. This works well for simple typing, but breaks whenever the user tries to paste text from Word or another webpage. The resulting HTML will be littered with style attributes and will look like it was literally cut and pasted from the source.

**I need to filter the HTML some way.** This can be done client-side, giving a smooth interface for the user where pasted material fits instantly into my app's style.

**Of course, the user can override my filtering.** So to protect myself fully from tag soup hell, I would need to perform the same filtering again, server-side. This is similar to the form validation problem.

**I don't want to duplicate the filtering logic** in both jQuery (client-side) and Ruby (server-side) but I don't know if there's any good way to avoid it. So far I have identified two possibilities:

- Implement all filtering server-side, access it from the client by AJAX. This will put a heavy load on the server.
- Implement filtering fully in JS, run on client and on server through Node.js. I don't know if there is enough similarity between the two platforms to implement a shared filtering routine. Libraries like [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) look promising though.

**Has anyone solved a similar problem before?** I would appreciate any guidance to keep my app as DRY as possible.

Comment: Pretty much in same boat. It also depends on the browser as to what code soup it tosses in the mix when pasting from Word. Have you had any luck?

Comment: @kcdwayne I decided to take the long road and build separate filters on the client and server sides. The server passes the filtered content back to the client in the response to the client's PUT request, so the user gets to see what was actually saved. It seems to work ok. One thing that took some time was to filter away nested <script> tags. Script tags are treated as implicit CDATA blocks by some parsers. So be sure to filter away any CDATA blocks as these can only lead to trouble and XSS attacks.